# Connect Panache to multiple Datasources

Tags: java, quarkus, multiple-databases, quarkus-panache

Is there any way to use Panache with multiple datasources?

I'd like to use Panache instead of creating native queries when I'm using another database.

At the moment, I can only use Panache in the default datasource, when I need to perform some query in another database, it is necessary to use @PersistenceUnit with the EntityManager in the repository, thus creating a native query.

Answer (score 1):

You can, it's documented [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#multiple-persistence-units).

Use the right `@PersistenceUnit` on your entities, and Hibernate with Panache will use under the cover the right `EntityManager`. There is nothing specific that should be used on the Panache side.

You can even get access to the right `EntityManager` using `MyEntity.getEntityManager()` or `myRepository.getEntityManager()` as Panache will use the information from the `@PersistenceUnit` to select it.